# macOS Big Sur - unnotarized 3rd party quick look plugin?

Tags: big-sur, quicklook, notarization

After updating to macOS Big Sur 11.0.1, a 3rd party epub quicklook plugin stopped working:

[image]

I've already forgotten how I installed the plugin (from Homebrew cask or downloaded from the web, but judging from the error message, it was the latter one). If it's an unnotarized GUI app, I'd remove the `com.apple.quarantine` attribute from the app so that it would work, but I don't know how to do that with a quick look plugin.

Is there a way to make the plugin work?

Answer (score 4):

You do the same thing as with an app. QuickLook plugins are installed to `~/Library/QuickLook`.

You can run `xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine ~/Library/QuickLook` to remove the com.apple.quarantine attribute from all QuickLook plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. Maybe it's not a QL plugin?

Comment: Ah, apologies. This is a Spotlight plugin as well as a QuickLook plugin. Check that `epub.mdimporter` is in `~/Library/Spotlight`, and run `xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine ~/Library/Spotlight` to remove `com.apple.quarantine` from the Spotlight plugins folder.

Comment: It's weird bcz I couldn't find `~/Library/Spotlight` dir on Big Sur...